# Kafka Topic Not Compacting

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Kafka topic with 25 partitions with the following topic settings:

```
delete.retention.ms=5000
cleanup.policy=compact
compression.type=lz4
```

It has about 10 billion records in it, across about 13 segments per partition. The oldest segment is a few months old.

The brokers are running Confluent Platform 5.0.1 (Kafka 2.0) and are set to continuously compact:

```
# Ensure compaction runs continuously
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.00001

# Set a limit on compaction so there is bandwidth for regular activities
log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=100000000

log.segment.bytes=1073741824
```

This is per the Confluent post concerning GDPR & compaction: [GDPR & Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/handling-gdpr-log-forget/)

**The problem**

The log is not compacting. 90% of the topic should have been removed by now. Many of the records have null values, which should clear them out; the rest of the records that I expect to be removed have duplicate keys.

There are no errors in the log cleaner logs and I can see it cleaning the later segments in the topic.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your segment is full? Do you have at least 2 segments per topic; one which is full, and the other which is the active one?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous We have at least a few billion records total. Even across 25 partitions, we have about a dozen segments per partition.

Comment: `log.cleaner.enable` is it true?

Comment: @Steephen It's true by default as of 0.9, but I explicitly set it to true on one of the brokers and I'm testing it now. I'm not seeing any additional activity that would indicate a difference, though.

Comment: `log.roll.hours` OR `log.roll.ms` check those ?

Comment: `log.roll.hours=24`. Some of the records that should be removed via compaction are months old.

Comment: Does the log cleaner logs show any errors, or has that file been updated recently?

Comment: @cricket_007 The log cleaner logs were last updated today and have no errors or warnings.